# Making one to many relation array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, underscore.js

I have two arrays of objects:

```
var a = [{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "q"
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "l"
}]
```

and another is

```
var b = [{
  "id": 3,
  "sub": 1,
  "name": "ni"
},
{
  "id": 4,
  "sub": 2,
  "name": "bh"
}]
```

Here sub is the id in `a`

I need to have a new array which will look like this:

```
var c = [
  {
    "id":1,
    "name":"q",
    "map":[
      {
        "id":3,
        "name":"ni"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id":2,
    "name":"l",
    "map":[
      {
        "id":4,
        "name":"bh"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

How can I do that in JavaScript?

I am using underscore in my project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In plain Javascript you could use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and a hash table.

```js
var a = [{ "id": 1, "name": "q" }, { "id": 2, "name": "l" }],
    b = [{ "id": 3, "sub": 1, "name": "ni" }, { "id": 4, "sub": 2, "name": "bh" }],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result = a.map(function (a, i) {
        hash[a.id] = { id: a.id, name: a.name };
        return hash[a.id];
    }, hash);

b.forEach(function (a) {
    hash[a.sub].map = hash[a.sub].map || [];
    hash[a.sub].map.push({ id: a.id, name: a.name });
}, hash);

console.log(result);
```

ES6

```js
var a = [{ "id": 1, "name": "q" }, { "id": 2, "name": "l" }],
    b = [{ "id": 3, "sub": 1, "name": "ni" }, { "id": 4, "sub": 2, "name": "bh" }],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result = a.map((hash => a => hash[a.id] = { id: a.id, name: a.name, map: [] })(hash));

b.forEach((hash => a => hash[a.sub].map.push({ id: a.id, name: a.name }))(hash));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: In the ES6 code, it says `Arrow function should not return assignment` in this line `result = a.map((hash => a => hash[a.id] = { id: a.id, name: a.name, map: [] })(hash));`

Comment: which browser do you use?

Comment: I am doing this in Node.js

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the help of `map` function and then use the `find` function to search the data from the other array.

```js
var b = [{
    "id": 3,
    "sub": 1,
    "name": "ni"
}, {
    "id": 4,
    "sub": 2,
    "name": "bh"
}];
var a = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "q"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "l"
}];

var final = _.map(b, function(d) {
    return {
        id: d.name,
        name: d.name,
        map: _.find(a, function(adata) {
            return adata.id == d.sub; //use underscore find to get the relevant data from array a
        })
    }
});

console.log(final);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: They key `map` inside `final` is not an array of objects. I need an array.